# i am root but ufw status says 'command not found'

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, root

as simple user, first I pass root with command :

`su`

I am now root on Debian 10 buster.

When I hit `ufw status`, I have 'command not found'. But it works with `sudo ufw status`

When I use `su -`, the command is ok.

Can someone explain me this problem / this difference between `su` and `su -` and why the command is not found even if I am root in the first case ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is with `-` you can export path env variables etc. but not with only `su`, Kindly refer this [page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html).

```
   -, -l, --login
       Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar
       to a real login:

       •   clears all the environment variables except TERM and
           variables specified by --whitelist-environment

       •   initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER,
           LOGNAME, and PATH

       •   changes to the target user’s home directory

       •   sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make the
           shell a login shell
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the exact answer.